# What is the UX behind showing cleaner profiles on cleaning-on-demand apps?

Tags: app, selling-ux, service-design

When I am using an app to order cleaners to clean my house, many apps show the profile of cleaners with ratings. As a user, I do not care who cleans the house as long as my house is super clean. What could be the UX thought behind showing profiles of cleaners while using the service?

Comment: This is the similar to the displaying features, reviews and ratings of an item in e-commerce. This is the way to build trust and persuade customer.

Comment: Assuming the purpose of the app is to let you choose the best cleaner, surely you'd want some sort of review/rating system in order to make a judgement?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the user experience behind the decision we won't know for sure. But please do not assume that your preference is the same with other users or targeted users for this app. 
For example my father needed a cleaning lady in his house but we couldn't convince him until we told him who the person was, whose house she cleaned before and other information, so you can see that users have different needs. Maybe you are a power user and just look at ratings and some need to also see the profile in detail to get convinced.

Answer (score 0):

Most often, user experiences are target and audience-specific and the UX designer is geared with the responsibility of making an experience that blends with all or majority of the audience he intends to reach.

While a user might just be interested in anybody cleaning the house, another user might be also be interested in how the cleaner has been rated by previous users, yet another user might not be interested in these and just feels like he/she wants someone that is named 'Wurah' to clean his/her house.

As variety for the audience differ, the user experience should be able to cover all of these diversities in an appealing manner.

It would now be left for the user to decide which information are of his/her concerns.